# Repeating a formula for every row in Pages

Tags: pages, numbers, iwork

I'm working on a simple formula in Pages where I have a table with 4 cells per row.

Product Name, Purchase Price, Quantity and Total.
[image]

I've created a simple formula that multiples Purchase Price with Quantity and displays the result in the Total row.

My problem is that I am at this time unaware of how many rows I will be requiring. So my questions is, is it possible to every new row I create inherit these properties / this formula when added?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, tables have a small yellow dot on the highlight box at the bottom once selected.

Clicking and dragging this dot downwards will duplicate the rows (and hence their enclosed formulae).